# Match empty value after equals

Tags: powershell

I have a variable `$file` with log file text from a MSI installer, example lines:

```
Property(S): PhysicalMemory = 4096
Property(S): DesktopFolder = C:\Users\Public\Desktop\
Property(S): SourceDir = C:\Scripts\
```

Some lines have no value after `=`:

```
Property(S): Foo = 
Property(S): Bar =
```

Now I'm trying to return only those lines, I have tried:

```
$file -match "=  *"
$file | Select-String -Pattern "=  *"
```

Both return all lines with matching pattern. And:

```
$file | Select-String -SimpleMatch "=  *"
```

Which returns nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a whitespace character after the equals?  If so, you can catch it like so: `-match '=\s+$'`.  Otherwise, you can catch it like: `-match '=$'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't too surprising. `*` in regex means "zero or more" so of course you will return everything.

Do the lines always end after the `=` ? If so, check for the end of string with `$`:

```
$line -match '=\s*$'
```

I'm using `\s` to catch whitespace of any kind, and `*` to capture all of the possible whitespace if there's any at all.

Then using `$` to match the end of the string.

Comment: and `-SimpleMatch` does not support wildcards of any kind.